# Why do I redirect to Google ipv4-URL CAPTCHA when I do specific search many times?

Tags: google-search

I am trying to find some solution in the Google regarding asp.net keyword, it's works fine for several times.
But suddenly, 
The last time I just tried to search "asp.net" on Google, it shown me [the following page](https://ipv4.google.com/sorry/IndexRedirect?continue=https://www.google.it/search%3Fq%3Dsoffione%26es_sm%3D119%26biw%3D1872%26bih%3D898%26source%3Dlnms%26sa%3DX%26ei%3DndCeVLySJcHNygOpmYLQDw%26ved%3D0CAUQ_AUoAA%26dpr%3D1&q=CGMSBF0hSJcYoaH7pAUiGQDxp4NLT0w7Kh5B77IZ9U3KTEB43pInd6k); note the `ipv4.google.com` hostname in the URL.

This problem appears also in my Android phone. I don’t understand why, Just want to know why this occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of google find un-usual traffice from your end. so google just wants to confirm that user is human it is not a any pre-command bug which can give un-usual traffice to google server.

be pations and give correct captacha code .. either you can close your browser and do your search once again on google.

Comment: and i gives you advise that please search google in sign-in mode so you will not face this again

Comment: i have tried both, close the browser and enter captcha but still it's redirect me to the same page.

Comment: I have already sing-in google, that's y facing same issue in my android phone as well.

Comment: so thing is that google server confused about your identity. that's why this is happening

Answer (score 2):

It's written at the bottom of the page:

> Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network.
>   This page checks to see if it's really you sending the requests, and
>   not a robot. Why did this happen?

Comment: Yeah it's correct,  but I mean in how much it's recover coz everyday when I searched the ss result is appread...???